# How to Convert Numbers (from 1 to 99) to the Equivalent Arabic Ordinal Number String

Tags: javascript, numbers, arabic

## Convert Numbers (from 1 to 99) to Arabic Ordinal Number String

Unlike English Ordinal Numbers where the ordinal number is made from the original number (in digital form) and a suffix is added to it (i.e. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th......), the Arabic Ordinal Numbers cannot be written like that and an Arabic Ordinal Number **is a full-text representation**.

The table below lists selected Arabic Ordinal Numbers (from 1 to 99).

Arabic Ordinal Numbers differ if the subject is Masculine or Feminine.

There is no Javascript function or a solution on StackOverflow that can be found that can convert a number (in the range from 1 to 99) to the equivalent Arabic Ordinal Number text taking into account the type of the subject (Masculine or Feminine).

An example of such a function could be:

```
ordinalsAr(5);
ordinalsAr(21);

// result ==> الخامس
// result ==> الحادي والعشرون

ordinalsAr(5, true);   // true flag for Feminine
ordinalsAr(21, true);  // true flag for Feminine

// result ==> الخامسة
// result ==> الحادية والعشرون
```

| Arabic Ordinal Numbers |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| English Ordinals | English Ordinals | Arabic Ordinals | Arabic Ordinals |
| N° | Ordinal Number | Masculine | Feminine |
| 1st | First | الأول | الأولى |
| 2nd | Second | الثاني | الثانية |
| 3rd | Third | الثالث | الثالثة |
| 4th | Fourth | الرابع | الرابعة |
| 5th | Fifth | الخامس | الخامسة |
| 6th | Sixth | السادس | السادسة |
| 7th | Seventh | السابع | السابعة |
| 8th | Eighth | الثامن | الثامنة |
| 9th | Ninth | التاسع | التاسعة |
| 10th | Tenth | العاشر | العاشرة |
| 11th | Eleventh | الحادي عشر | الحادية عشرة |
| 12th | Twelfth | الثاني عشر | الثانية عشرة |
| 13th | Thirteenth | الثالث عشر | الثالثة عشرة |
| 14th | Fourteenth | الرابع عشر | الرابعة عشرة |
| 15th | Fifteenth | الخامس عشر | الخامسة عشرة |
| 16th | Sixteenth | السادس عشر | السادسة عشرة |
| 17th | Seventeenth | السابع عشر | السابعة عشرة |
| 18th | Eighteenth | الثامن عشر | الثامنة عشرة |
| 19th | Nineteenth | التاسع عشر | التاسعة عشرة |
| 20th | Twentieth | العشرون | العشرون |
| 21st | Twenty-first | الحادي والعشرون | الحادية والعشرون |
| 22nd | Twenty-second | الثاني والعشرون | الثانية والعشرون |
| 23rd | Twenty-third | الثالث والعشرون | الثالثة والعشرون |
| 24th | Twenty-fourth | الرابع والعشرون | الرابعة والعشرون |
| …. | …………. | …………. | …………. |
| 29th | Twenty-ninth | التاسع والعشرون | التاسعة والعشرون |
| 30th | Thirtieth | الثلاثون | الثلاثون |
| …. | …………. | …………. | …………. |
| 40th | Fortieth | الأربعون | الأربعون |
| …. | …………. | …………. | …………. |
| 99th | Ninety-Ninth | التاسع والتسعون | التاسعة والتسعون |

[image]

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: This is not a homework question. This is true problem not talked until now.

Comment: Just because it's never talked about doesn't mean you just dump the requirement with zero effort from your side. From what I see this isn't any different from other number to words. There are two different forms? Just store two array/dictionary then, and pull the correct words accordingly.

Comment: Will you store 200 elements array of string? That's too large a text file.

Comment: Not that large, this page alone is a few hundred KBs, 200 items should be less than a hundred kb. That said, obviously you can split the chunks by tens, I see a pattern on 11-19 and 20-29, solve that separately for both feminine and masculine form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Alan Omar's code concept, a shorter code to Convert Numbers (from 1 to 99) to Arabic Ordinal String is as follows.

More information about Arabic Numbers conversion can be found here [Arabic Numbers](http://allthearabicyouneverlearnedthefirsttimearound.com/p3/p3-ch3/arabic-numbers/)

```js
/*********************************************************************
* @function      : ordinalsAr(number [, isFeminine])
* @purpose       : Converts numbers from 1 to 99 to Arabic Ordinal String
* @version       : 1.00
* @author        : Mohsen Alyafei
* @date          : 27 Jan 2022
* @Licence       : MIT
* @param         : {number} Integer from 1 to 99
* @param         : [isFeminine] the subject's gender:
*                  false (default) --> Masculine subject (e.g. output الأول الثاني الثالث)
*                  true            --> Feminine subject  (e.g. output الأولى الثانية الثالثة)
* @returns       : {string} The ordinal Arabic Text.
**********************************************************************/


function ordinalsAr(num, isFeminine=false) {
num %= 100;                  // only handle the lowest 2 digits (1-99) ignore others
let    the = "ال",           // set this to "" if you don't want the output prefixed with letters "ال"
      unit = num % 10,
    ordinal= the + [,"أول","ثاني","ثالث","رابع","خامس","سادس","سابع","ثامن","تاسع","عاشر"]
                   [num === 10 ? num : unit],                       // letters for lower part of ordinal string
    female = isFeminine ? "ة" : "",                                 // add letter "ة" if Feminine
      ones = (unit === 1 ? the + "حادي" : ordinal) + female;        // special cases for 21, 31, 41, etc.
return num <11 ? ordinal + (isFeminine && num ===1 ? "ى" : female): // from 1 to 10
       num <20 ? ones + " عشر" + female :                           // from 11 to 19
       (unit ? ones + " و" : "") +                                  // else 20 to 99
       "ال" +                                                       // always add "ال"
       [,,"عشر","ثلاث","أربع","خمس","ست","سبع","ثمان","تسع"]       // letters for 20, 30, 40...
       [ ~~(num / 10)] + "ون";
}
// *=======================================================


//=======================================
//             Test Cases
//=======================================
// List the ordinal numbers from 1 to 99
// in both Masculine and Feminine genders
//=======================================
for (let i=1; i<100; i++) {
console.log(i,"M:  "+ordinalsAr(i),
              "F:  "+ordinalsAr(i,true) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function ordinalsAr(num,isFeminine){

    let feminineSuffix = "ة";

    let specialNums = {
        1:{
            masculine: "الأول",
            feminine: "الأولى"
        },
        10:{
            masculine: "العاشر",
            feminine: "العاشرة"
        }
    }
    
    let lastDigits = {
        10:"عشر",
        20:"العشرون",
        30:"الثلاثون",
        40:"الأربعون",
        50:"الخمسون",
        60:"الستون",
        70:"السبعون",
        80:"الثمانون",
        90:"التسعون",
        // you have to add the rest here
    }

    let firstDigits = {
            1:"الحادي",
            2:"الثاني",
            3:"الثالث",
            4:"الرابع",
            5:"الخامس",
            6:"السادس",
            7:"السابع",
            8:"الثامن",
            9:"التاسع",
    }
   
    if (specialNums[num])
        return isFeminine ? specialNums[num]['feminine'] : specialNums[num]['masculine']

    if(firstDigits[num])
        return isFeminine ? firstDigits[num] + feminineSuffix : firstDigits[num]

    if(lastDigits[num])
        return lastDigits[num]
    
    let firstDigit = num % 10;
    let lastDigit = num - firstDigit
    
    if (isFeminine) {
        if(lastDigit < 20)
            return firstDigits[firstDigit] + feminineSuffix + " " + lastDigits[lastDigit] + feminineSuffix
        else
            return firstDigits[firstDigit] + feminineSuffix + " و" + lastDigits[lastDigit]
    }
    
    else{
        if(lastDigit < 20)
            return firstDigits[firstDigit] + " " + lastDigits[lastDigit]
    
    }

    return firstDigits[firstDigit] + " و" + lastDigits[lastDigit]
}

console.log(ordinalsAr(1))
console.log(ordinalsAr(1,true))
console.log(ordinalsAr(10))
console.log(ordinalsAr(25,true))
console.log(ordinalsAr(35))
console.log(ordinalsAr(19))
console.log(ordinalsAr(19,true))

//===================================
//   Additional Test Cases
//===================================
// convert all numbers from 1 to 99
// in both male and female genders
//===================================
for (let i=1; i<100; i++) {
console.log(i,ordinalsAr(i),
          ordinalsAr(i,true) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alan. This works great.  I have added test cases for numbers 1 to 49 as your code only covered ordinal numbers from 1 to 49. But can be easily extended.

Comment: Sure no problem i hope this works fine for you.

Comment: I have made an update based on your code concept.